# Opening cmd window which is running a command

Tags: cmd

I want to open a cmd window which is already running a command, e.g something like `cmd echo Hello, world!` or something like that.

Comment: Are you looking for a *.bat file?

Comment: I'm looking for a python os.system("command to open cmd window running command") specifically if that helps

Comment: `cmd /k your command`

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a .bat file
2. Write following codes

`echo 'Hello, World'`

3. Call your .bat path in your cmd.

*Another else

Open your run window

Run this commands

```
cmd /k echo 'Hello, World'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a **.bat** file or **.cmd** file and insert your code
2. Add the path of your file in your **PATH environment variable**
3. **WindowsKey + R**, to run the "Execute" programme
4. Just type the name or your **bat** or **cmd** file. You can call it from *cmd* anywhere in your computer

Don't miss to add *pause* at the end of your program. This allows you to close it manually. use *@echo off pause* to avoid showing the code execute